# defined <td> in differnt rows, width not working

Tags: html, html-table, width, newsletter

Back to 1998! I am working on a newsletter template witht tables! My issue is that my `td` is not taking the `width` defined but is inherting it!

The bottom two rows in the sample have three columns each! In the top row I need the side columns as defined to be `42px`, and the bottom row to be `83px`. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong! Thank you!

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table bgcolor="#c1d781" width="503px" align="center" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <p mc:edit="element-title">„Lorem Lorem Lorem“</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="10px" colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="42px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" width="420px">
          <p mc:edit="element-teaser">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sapien.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </p>
        </td>
        <td width="42px">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50px" colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="83px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" width="337px">
          <p mc:edit="element-button"><a href="#">BUTTON</a>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td width="83px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="60px" colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You cant have different column widths per row in a single table. You could nest tables though - So each row holds a single cell in which you place a nested table of 1 row with 3 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do isn't supported in a single table (and rightly so). A table is like a grid - you can't have different column widths per row. You can however solve this by nesting tables.

In this example each row holds a single cell in which you place a nested table of 1 row with 3 cells:

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table bgcolor="#c1d781" width="503px" align="center" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p mc:edit="element-title">„Lorem Lorem Lorem“</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="10px"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <td width="42px">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" width="420px">
                <p mc:edit="element-teaser">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sapien.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>
              </td>
              <td width="42px">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50px"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <td width="83px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" width="337px">
                <p mc:edit="element-button"><a href="#">BUTTON</a>
                </p>
              </td>
              <td width="83px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="60px"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```